# Некорректное отображение графика репутации

Tags: дефект, репутация, страница-учётной-записи

1. При отображении графика репутации на большом временном отрезке происходит вывод лишь части данных.

   К примеру, для *@VladD* график на всём периоде существования профиля выглядит так:

   > [image: экранный снимок]

   Проблема заключается в том, что **на графике отображаются всего лишь три группы ненулевых значений**. На самом же деле репутация имела положительный прирост на всей выборке (согласно предпросмотру, а также вертикальному смещению нуля графика, чтобы поместились отрицательные столбики). Да и всплывающая подсказка выводится даже там, где график не отрисован.

   При этом количество и положение отображаемой области остаётся тем же даже при уменьшении временного интервала:

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   Похожая проблема (только в виде узких пропусков) проявляется, хоть и частично, и на более малых периодах:

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Являются ли нормой пустые поля справа и слева от графика?

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Интересный баг!

Comment: [возможный дубликат на Мета.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280545/339911).

Comment: Или вот [еще](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207931/339911).